# Which are the non-x text editors in Powershell?

Tags: console, powershell, text-editors

Are there some editors like emacs, vi/vim,  specifically for power shell, if so which are the best?

I will have to do some work on windows and I need some unix productivity - which means for me
shell + text editor with syntax highlighting (for python, java, c, c++), so which are my options?

**Edit:**
I'm looking for an alternative at vim or other unix editors, and cygwin is not an option.
I just want from the command line to say *texteditor_name file1*, 
modify it, save it etc, and all of these to happen inside the terminal, not
in another interface etc.

Comment: there is no sane internal editor (comparable with vim/emacs) that comes right out of the box with windows. vim is available as a native windows binary for 32 and 64bit, and it works in the console (aka textmode).

Comment: Did you try [PowerShell SE](http://powershelltools.com) IDE?

Comment: @apm PowerShell ISE is an IDE. It is _not_ a command shell. That's the biggest turn-off.

Comment: the graphical interface in Windows is **not** called X

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Vim is available](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) as a straight-up Windows port if you prefer it.  I have an older version that installed itself with batch files; that doesn't integrate into Cygwin so well, but it's workable.  I haven't tried v7 yet.

I'm sure there's Emacs for Windows, but I'll let you dig that link up on your own.  ;)

Comment: i'm kidding, here ya go: http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/windows/ ... i don't know anything about these builds (other than they are straight from GNU) ... the first google link was a "compile it on Windows!" FAQ.  (also from GNU...)

Answer (score 4):

why not use [vim](http://vim.org) with '[powershell syntax](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1327)'?

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party but this editor works great from the command line.

**Kinesics Text Editor**
http://www.turtlewar.org/projects/editor/

It also has a UI version as well.

After install you can use it at the command line by typing 'k'.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was grabbed Nano w. the WinNT binary from: http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php

I threw that folder into an idea folder and then added it to the Windows System PATH. :3 (Start -> Right Click "Computer" -> Properties -> System protection -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System variables.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but I want to recommend you `micro` https://micro-editor.github.io/index.html . It works in Window, it has "new-style" keyboard binding, it support UTF-8.